# install codec with C#

Tags: c#, windows

**how to install AVI X263 codec with C# . So it possible to play that avi file with windows media player.**

Is theere any diffrenet codec that Windows Meidal Player can Play them.

My vide size is 1024 *768 .

Answer (score 1):

```
Process.Start(@"c:\install\avix263codec\setup.exe");
```

Comment: I knew this ! but I want to to them automatically.